# Best Way To Find Independent Designers?

Tags: resource-recommendations

What is the best way to find an independent designer for a particular field? For example, one that has a portfolio and designs book-covers/print/packaging, ...? It is a requirement for me to draw inspiration from in my project. (I'm a student)

It's slightly difficult nowadays. (For example, a designer for book-covers would be Peter Mendelsund.)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [AIGA](http://www.aiga.org/). They are a national group of designers and chances are you will have a local chapter that you can get in contact with and they will lead you in the right direction for your design needs. Otherwise, as mentioned in an earlier post, you could check out portfolio sites like [Behance](http://www.behance.net/) or even try [LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com). Other avenues to find independent designers would be to scour design contest sites like [99 Designs](http://99designs.com/). There's no shortage in finding them, the tricky part is finding good ones :)

Answer (score 1):

Check [odesk](http://www.odesk.com).

It is a bit expensive, though.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say where you are, but in United States there is the [Graphic Artists Guild](http://www.graphicartistsguild.org/) and there are some regional book builders association like [Boston Bookbuilders](http://www.bbboston.org/). Both sites have lists of members that might be of assistance, but you're right in that finding designers when the designers don't come to you is difficult.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.behance.net/ is quite nice to see other people's work.

The idea is to showcase your work, connect with other people and as it covers a lot of creative fields, you can find pretty much any kind of design work there...

Try to, for example, search for "book cover".
Here is one result: `www.behance.net/gallery/Book-Covers/290073`

Answer (score 1):

http://browse.deviantart.com/  There are plenty of artists and their work on there.  I would  give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Also check out [dribbble.com](http://dribbble.com) for visual designers.

Answer (score 0):

check out shutterstock.com if you like a particular artwork you can click on that and then it shows you the owner of the artwork you can click on the profile and can contact him personally via email or anything which he has mentioned in his bio! also you can check out his portfolio in shutterstock!

Answer (score -2):

The best way is to search on the internet or you can easily hire freelance graphic designer for your graphic design needs via [Designhill](http://www.designhill.com/) which is my own website.

Comment: When linking your own site its important you disclose that. Its StackExchange policy and just general good policy.